# Count the number of unique values from these two columns

Tags: pandas

I would like to count the number of unique values from the columns bellow. Numpy will find the values that match between these two columns: 123 and 454, hence the value of count is equal to 2. But now, how can i count the remaining values: 787, 325 and 661 ? The output should be 3.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ["123","454", "787"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'IA': ["325", "123", "454", "661"]})

count = np.in1d(df['ID'], df2['IA']).sum()
```

Comment: Although that seems to be different from what your question is actually asking: the number of unique values in df['ID']. It isn't too clear what you want.

Comment: @SebastienD They're not a new contributor, this is one of possibly [many accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56652152/comparing-values-within-two-rows). Think I know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

To get unique elements from a *Series* (e.g. *DataFrame* column) call:

```
df.ID.unique()
```

To count these values add `size`:

```
df.ID.unique().size
```

`size` is an **attribute** (not a function), so there are no parentheses.

If you want to count unique elements in **both** columns, join them together
into a single *Series*, (calling *append*) and then call *.unique().size*:

```
df.ID.append(df2.IA).unique().size
```